# How to get record count/class distribution for every tree node in Spark MLlib Random Forest?

Tags: apache-spark, tree, nodes, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I am doing a two-class classification using Random Forest in Spark 1.5.0 MLlib. I want to get the count of records for each class in every tree node. Is there a way to do this? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, or at least not through the exposed APIs. You can get all the trees in a random tree model using [trees()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/RandomForestModel.html#trees()). In each tree you can get all nodes starting from the [topNode()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/DecisionTreeModel.html#topNode()) and in each Node you can get [InformationGainStats](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/InformationGainStats.html) which will tell you about your [information gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_in_decision_trees) and impurities but the number of elements after the split is not stored. Not sure it would be necessary in general case, after all usually you don't care how big the new subset is but how chaotic it is in terms of your classes.

If you need probabilities maybe the [Predict](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/Predict.html) class will be enough for you?

Comment: Thank you Mateusz for the prompt answer and very helful information! What I need is to create rules from tree nodes based on the false positive rate (FPR) of a node. If a node has FPR < 10 then I want to create a rule for that node. Will and how the `Predict` class you mentioned help to do this?

Comment: It would be useful to know the distribution at each node if you wanted to visualize the structure of the decision tree.

Answer (score 1):

First, export your Random Forest model in PMML data format. Then, score your dataset again using the [JPMML-Evaluator library](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator) and capture the score and the Node id of each prediction. Finally, group the results.

This approach works for any ML software/tree model type combination. For example, you can analyze R and Scikit-Learn RF, GBM, XGBoost etc models exactly the same way.